# Unable to sign PDF document (Can't write new byteRange - not enough space)

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, digital-signature

I'm having trouble signing a PDF. This is a fillable French administrative form, and I've tried :

- signing it filled
- signing it blank
- signing it with Docusign or Certeurope

But none of that will work.

Docusign doesn't give much verbose when signature fails, however here is the error from the Certeurope API:

```
java.io.IOException: Can't write new byteRange '0 1346202 1358004 33008]' not enough space: byteRange.length(): 24, byteRangeLength: 20
```

From what I have researched online, this should happen when the signature appliance tries to apply a signature to a document but has reserved a byterange that is too narrow. I'm a bit clueless here, however, as we sign thousands of documents per month with Docusign and Certeurope and never encountered that issue. It seems to be specific to this document.

I am also surprised that the byterange for the signature seems to go all the way to 1346202, for the first part, when the original un-signed document is only ~648k bytes.

The original document is available here https://www.impots.gouv.fr/portail/files/formulaires/2759-sd/2021/2759-sd_3462.pdf

Any clue as to what might be happening?

Comment: One should have a look at the source code. We reserve space for [0 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000] so that should be enough. Unless they modified this by calling `setByteRange()` on the  signature object. Another possibility could be confusion due to UR3 signature which has also a byteRange. I don't get the bug with current PDFBox, maybe they are using an older version.

Comment: You say you've tried *signing it filled*, *signing it blank*, and *signing it with Docusign or Certeurope*. Which software/services have you used in the former two cases? Case number 3 clearly is a case for the respective service address of those services.